# Command xkill doesn't work : no + cursor

Tags: command-line, 22.04, wayland, cursor, xkill

I have a minor problem with the command `xkill`.

Once I enter the command line `xkill`, there is no error message, but the cursor doesn't turn into a cross like it should normally do:

```
msi@msi-GF63-8RC➜ ~ xkill
Select the window whose client you wish to kill with button 1....
```

I have try : `sudo apt-get install x11-utils` which indicate that I do have the newest version :

```
msi@msi-GF63-8RC➜ ~ sudo apt-get install x11-utils
[sudo] password for msi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
x11-utils is already the newest version (7.7+5build2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS version, with Wayland.

It worked before and I didn't do anything special. If anyone have an idea on the problem's origin and how to solve it, I will be thankful. If you need additional informations please tell me.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You are on a Wayland session, so `xkill` will not work, because as the "x" in its name suggests, it works on X only. So you have to use an Xorg session. To use an Xorg session: log out of your current session, then click your user's avatar, click on the cog icon on the bottom right, select *GNOME on Xorg*, and then log in with your password. See if `xkill` works then.

Comment: I run Wayland and I can use `xkill` with no problem. However, I can't kill every window. E.g. Spotify and VLC work, but Sublime (text editor) and Thunderbird do not.

Comment: @Jos Really? Are you sure you don't have an alias for it? Did it got an update that makes it work in Wayland, because I'm not aware of it and I'm actually surprised that you say it works!

Comment: @Jos Based on your edited comment, perhaps it works for apps using XWayland.

Comment: I am sure that I run Wayland ($XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland) and `which xkill` gives me `/usr/bin/xkill`, which is a 14648-byte executable. So no alias. I'm on Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: Thank you @BeastOfCaerbannog and @Jos, your explanation was clear and easy to understand. As @Jos said I was able to use `xkill` on Wayland before ( on firefox or chrome ) but not anymore. So I wonder what happen. Unfortunately Xorg session doesn't work.